# Metis Silver Fang - is such thing even possible?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

When it comes to treating metis born Garou, I know that from one side of the spectrum we have Children of Gaia/Bone Gnawers that treat them as equal, on the other: Fianna who see them as monsters and Get of Fenris/Shadow Lords who treat them as a weaklings and liability. But what about Silver Fangs? Imagine, that the two noble born committed such "incest" and such bastard is blemishing the honor and good name of the line. I believe that such children are usually smothered in the crib or at best send away. Yes, they can get back to the tribe...but then what about the Falcon - would the spirit admit that such offspring is one of his children?

Maybe I am wrong, but in my opinion Metis SF should be as rare as Silent Strider with access to Ancestors.

Answer (score 7):

This is very late, but there is actually an official listed metis Silver Fang!

> **Two Tails** is a Metis Ragabash Silver Fang cub. He seeks vengeance for unspecified reasons.

There's no exact information on his treatment, or if his vengeance might perhaps be related to it being very poor, but the fact he was born and obviously survived past birth, is at least precedence to people like him existing!

Answer (score 3):

### They Exist *in the final days*

First of all, there is no rule that bans their existence, and with [Two Tails](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/143346/30306) there is at least one canonical example. But there are more, and each Tribebook delivered on one "pregen archetype character" with a history of its own, but which can be seen as a canonical character too.

- The Ice Dancer Archetype was born from a Vietnamese-Canadian Stargazer and a French-Canadian Silverfang.<sup>1</sup>
- The Class Clown Archetype visited a *Kinfolk Academy* in a class of three without knowing their parents.<sup>2</sup>

### They didn't always exist

The tribebooks make clear, that the stance on Crinos-born shifted, and preventing actively or culling them has not happened for the last 200 years. They are described as... well, regrettable it seems in the first Tribebook:

> Garou shall not mate with Garou
>
> We've obeyed this tenet scrupulously throughout most
> of our history; metis Silver Fangs were all but unknown
> before the 18th century. Since that time, however, worsening situations have led some of us to turn to our own kind
> for comfort and procreation. While these characters are in
> the vast minority, their number is growing. Offspring of
> these unions are pariahs in most houses, and are particu-
> larly unbalanced.<sup>3</sup>

### They are the lowest members of the Tribe

Now, the best description of how the Silver Fangs handle such is from the other Tribebook:

> Garou Shall Not Mate With Garou
>
> All Garou know the punishment for breaking this
> tenet: the birth of a metis Garou. These poor creatures
> bring shame on us all, for they are living reminders that
> we cannot control our passions in the name of Gaia.
> Those who commit such sin should be singled out and
> marked for it: the sigil of the oathbreaker should be
> carved into their backs, where they cannot erase it. As
> for the metis, they are not to blame, but neither should
> they be held as anything but impure. They should be
> given a place in Garou society, but among the lowest.<sup>4</sup>

It is clear from both Tribebooks that the attitude of "smother them in the crib" has been abandoned **long** ago. It's the parents fault, the deformed child can still be an asset in Garou Society, even if as a bad example and at the outskirts. The Class Clown again tells us that the tribe sequesters their crinos-born and teaches them in one location as smaller groups.<sup>2</sup>

---

1 - Tribebook Silver Fangs, 1st Edition, p. 58.
2 - Tribebook Silver Fangs, Revised Edition, p. 90.
3 - Tribebook Silver Fangs, 1st Edition, p. 30.
4 - Tribebook Silver Fangs, Revised Edition, p. 52.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. But the official material does not agree with us.

The Silver Fang tribebook, in the Lethany section, says that Metis were unknown within the tribe untril the 18th century. The urging situation has made some Silver Fangs to create Metis. They are still very few, but their numbers are growing.

The tribebook I was looking was second edition, but I bet they would be the same in other revisions. I think the real reasons are gamists, they wanted that you could pick a Metis in any tribe you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why the Silver Fangs would have more than the standard stigma against Metis, honestly. They are big into breeding true, to the point where most normal members are at least a little inbred, so their seeing the metis as a blemish on their honor because they are a product of incest seems nonsensical. Falcon would definitely accept a metis, at least, since he apparently happily accepts the scads of inbred homid in the tribe.